# Can I stop the Google talk client checking my gmail?

Tags: email, instant-messaging, google-talk

I want to use Google talk, but I don't want it checking my email and notifying me of new mail all the time. I can't see how to switch it off, but it seems like the sort of thing that should be an option. Am I missing something? How can I switch email support off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To diable notification for new mail in Google Talk, follow these steps:

1. Open the Google Talk application.
2. Click **Settings**.
3. Select **Notifications** from the left pane.
4. From the right pane, go to **New email** and uncheck the **Show notification** checkbox.
5. Click **OK**.

[image]

[Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2508/google_talk_disable_mail_notifications/)

Answer (score 1):

See [the help page](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&answer=24742):

> If you would rather not receive
>   notifications, you can disable some or
>   all of them. Here is how:
>
> - Click
>     'Settings' at the top of your Friends
>     list.
> - Highlight 'Notifications' along
>     the left side of the Settings window.
> - Untick the boxes next to the
>     notifications that you do not wish to
>     receive or tick the box next to
>     'Disable all notifications'.
> - Click 'OK'.

I don't have a Windows box here to try it on, but that should work...